# Integrating Ola money api in android always getting app not installed?

Tags: android

Hello all i am integrating ola money with in my android app now the problem i am facing is that in their docs it is given that first check for whether the app is installed and for that they have given below code to see that, now i am having ola cabs app installed in my android device but this function is returning false i dont know what i am doing wrong, **if somebody has integrated ola in android please tellme how is it working for you**

```
private boolean check_olacabs() {
   try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.test.olacabs", 0); 
        return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
   }
}
```

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this.

```
private boolean check_olacabs() {

   PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

     try {
         pm.getPackageInfo("com.olacabs.customer", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
         return true;
     } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
         return false;
     }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man for your help it worked also can you please tell me inside startActivityForResult(intent); with intent i have to send one integer value also what have send example startActivityForResult(intent, number);

Comment: i mean with startActivityForResult we must send an integer with intent what is the number you send with the intent ??

Comment: we have to sent requestCode with startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) just to verify at the time of onActivityResult().
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Comment: also in my case what is happening is that when i am passing my intent to olacabs app then no balance page is showing i mean do i have to design that or what ??

Comment: code of my intent                                                                                                                           try {
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.olacabs.olamoney.pay");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
  intent.putExtra("bill", bill); //Pass the string representation of the json bill
  intent.setPackage("com.test.olacabs");
  startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  /*Activity not found exception - route the flow through webview*/   
}